# Botão de perguntas com recompensas não está traduzido

Tags: bug, tradução

O botão de perguntas com recompensas não está mais traduzido, antes estava ok:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sugestão de tradução para "Com recompensa" já foi dada no [Traducir](https://pt.traducir.win/string/11542).

Falta apenas algum usuário com a *role* *Reviewer* aprovar para possa ser encaminhada ao Transifex. Essa tradução está, inclusive, marcada como urgente, mas acredito que são pouquíssimos os usuários que estão utilizando a plataforma e fica muita coisa parada.

Comment: boa, aguardemos :)

Comment: já foi traduzido, obrigado